# Delayed Retrieval of Correct Firebase Remote Configuration After Updating User Properties

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am encountering a challenge with Firebase Remote Configuration. The issue pertains to a specific remote config parameter dependent on a particular user property. (We have conditional Remote Config parameter).

Condition is such that.
If the employee ID is B-1234 then the remote config value should be XYZ.
The default value of the parameter is ABC.

Here's the sequence of events:

1. User A (employeeID is A-5678) successfully logs into the app. Upon login, the `setUserProperty()` method from Analytics assigns the `employee_id` key with User-A’s `employeeID`.
2. When User A logs out, the `employee_id` user property is reset to null, using the same `setUserProperty()` method from Analytics.
3. Subsequently, User B (employeeID is B-1234) logs into the app. Again, the `setUserProperty()` method from Analytics assigns User B's `employeeID` to the `employee_id` key.

The issue arises when User B logs in and attempts to fetch the remote configuration. Initially, the default configuration is returned instead of User B's specific configuration. However, after a delay of approximately 1-2 minutes, the correct configuration for User B is eventually retrieved.

If this delay is due to the server not having updated properties, what stable solution can be recommended to mitigate this problem?